# ReplyKeyboardHide в PHP Telegram

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Нужно вообще удалить пользовательскую клавиатуру, все варианты ответов идут в keyboard, некоторые пользователи бота этого не догоняют и начинают что-то писать боту, возможно ли вообще отключить возможность ввода текста с помощью обычной клавиатуры и оставить только кнопки.

```
      $Keyboards = [["Информация"], ["Вариант А"]];
      $KeyboardSet = Array(
           "keyboard" => $Keyboards,
           "remove_keyboard" => true,
           'selective' => true
      );

      $ReplyMarkup = json_encode($KeyboardSet);
```

$ReplyMarkup вставляю в reply_markup, но все равно возможность ввода текста с клавиатуры остается!

Comment: А что Вы пытаетесь сделать этим кодом? Этот код вообще показывает кнопки?

Comment: Конечно, выводятся, я пытаюсь сделать чтобы после этого сообщения, самой возможности вводить текст с клавиатуры НЕ БЫЛО.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что продемонстрированным в вопросе кодом, Вы как раз-таки скрываете свою кастомную клавиатуру, т.к. по сигнатуре это похоже на реализацию [ReplyKeyboardRemove](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardremove).

В любом случае, полностью лишить пользователя возможности вводить сообщение не получится, поскольку это не реализовано в текущей версии Bot API. У пользователя всегда есть возможность переключаться между кастомной клавиатурой с кнопками и системной текстовой (см. скрины):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]